# RSA Decryption error

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, private-key

I am implementing RSA decryption. I have tried lot more things regarding RSA decryption and i have develop below code snipet.

```
public class AsymmetricEncryptionWithRSA {

  public void decryptdata1(){


    String PRIVATE_RSA_KEY_PKCS8 = 
            "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
            "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>rotP8p9dJpRM/D7HHW9wsRWJEBVdZolRR0PuYGp/Mjae2gElTZSBQ44ifOvVquI95ECDa2ypIrEz1k/mKRtHPmsSMqmySWL9CVsEZAc/zNfYjIKb4BDaFiBaPEsboebIEuaN3NFt2bbl/RB45TCycYylgDjCdFFASRbHs0jX4cM=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>\n" +
        "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
        String key = PRIVATE_RSA_KEY_PKCS8
            .replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "")
            .replace("\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "");
        System.out.println("key : "+key);

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec =
            new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(key));
        try {
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            String s = "kjZzSUPJBY4rM23P7t47W3RYPTqhEARCqOcgRfxxBSc3O2mxQZKE/HKDN9OzW5pc3K37rcd+Dc/d55uNJcJUWwmZL0vVgrQIBkQdSkrzcpXV9JD80Qgy8sCuHoqMU49U6I34I43+NUAFmQDkApHbMA8LGV6KLtoyIyUSpDiuW8Q=";
            byte[] ciphertextBytes = Base64.decode(s.getBytes());
            byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(ciphertextBytes);
            String decryptedString = new String(decryptedData);
            System.out.println("decrypted (plaintext) = " + decryptedString);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    AsymmetricEncryptionWithRSA ae = new AsymmetricEncryptionWithRSA();
    ae.decryptdata1();

  }
```

}

But the above code ran into the following error:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=11, too big.
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(Unknown Source)
    at decrypttest.AsymmetricEncryptionWithRSA.decryptdata1(AsymmetricEncryptionWithRSA.java:189)
    at decrypttest.AsymmetricEncryptionWithRSA.main(AsymmetricEncryptionWithRSA.java:210)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=11, too big.
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.newKey(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePrivate(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Did you read the error? `lengthTag=11, too big.`. It's a start.

Comment: @keyser : Can you please tell me what thing should i modify to solve the error

Comment: `InvalidKeyException`

Comment: Throw away this key, you've compromised it.

Comment: You key is: 1) *Not* a private key, and 2) *Not* in PKCS8 format.

Comment: @GregS : Can you please suggest me how that key should be converted into PKCS8 format. Because i have to decrypt the data using that key only. Please do needful.

Answer (score 0):

Crypto is frequently misunderstood, and thus I've decided to post a negative answer here. It's not very exciting, but if somebody finds themselves in scenario similar to the OPs they should probably be told why it can't work as early as possible in the process.

There are two possibilities when presented with a problem like this.

1. OP understands the problem correctly and they've been instructed to decrypt something with the public key.

or

2. OP does not completely understand their task but have been given a public key and some data and they need to make some progress with it.

For #1, it's simple: You can't decrypt [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem))-encrypted data using a public key. It turns out the OP has only an RSA public key here, provided in an XML format. There's no way to reformat, massage, or otherwise fix up the public key to make it into the private key needed to decrypt the message. If this were doable then RSA would be trivially weak.

Now for #2, we have to step back and think of what *might* be true. We often find question askers here on stack overflow referring to "encrypting with the private key" in a context that inevitably implies that they really have an instance of an RSA *signature*. Rather than *encryption*, for clarity this should be called *signing*. An RSA signature is generated using the private key, and then everyone can *verify* the signature using the public key.

Now to verify the signature you also need the data that was signed, though there are some uncommon RSA signature schemes that allow for "message recovery". Since we have no data in this question, we have to try to go through the steps of verifying an RSA signature until we can make no more progress.

So we convert the XML data into an RSA modulus and public exponent. They are:

modulus

```
n = 122569097529914546498069291857337865246611656055620489010618854241554260593577609267786261511762266943671570032800601669006596562960007716726461943599993657820822102674379936038822313418546881231271467615708966752462196756466881703206510681054434799028982952649926637620598591790584184591371562810823451075011
```

and public exponent

```
e = 65537
```

The next step is to convert the signature string `s` into an integer. Using base64 decoding and the treating the result byte as big-endian integer I get:

```
sig  = 102674047248928745858859342743181557926563805477311756100001889942342552706930945260621737497972422939132498975770606253415531107828422537100810225687174208681096157106683665614198008538708912251973616331643319025696474841958268570965587969021816350210845541576380037736081469197294740984924898949880343321540
```

And now I compute compute plain = sig<sup>e</sup> mod n and get:

```
plain  = 18281761513910757613247127600811463135393884768551021193363621715044011507027712128790112174797966270576132751506458211850250035395641481824697193105741034925363331241318624392861667609810000005509535564907655043671685464003456777077702725291701153287408411076758261166861253557068704213449855094306290667395
```

and finally convert plain to bytes using big endian to get:

```
92 36 73 49 43 c9 05 8e 2b 33 6d cf ee de 3b 5b 74 58 3d 3a a1 10 04 42 a8 e7 20 45 fc 71 05 27 37 3b 69 b1 41 92 84 fc 72 83 37 d3 b3 5b 9a 5c dc ad fb ad c7 7e 0d cf dd e7 9b 8d 25 c2 54 5b 09 99 2f 4b d5 82 b4 08 06 44 1d 4a 4a f3 72 95 d5 f4 90 fc d1 08 32 f2 c0 ae 1e 8a 8c 53 8f 54 e8 8d f8 23 8d fe 35 40 05 99 00 e4 02 91 db 30 0f 0b 19 5e 8a 2e da 32 23 25 12 a4 38 ae 5b c4
```

And ... nothing. It looks random to me, I see no patterns at all, nothing that looks like any possible version of [PKCS#1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017) padding including PSS, nothing that looks like a 'message recovery' format.

So I can't solve this, none of the obvious things to try yield anything. It may be that the OP has been given an RSA-encrypted message but only given a public key, or maybe this is one of those RSA capture-the-flag exercises for which there is some weakness that allows for factoring the modulus, or maybe the public key is wrong. Or maybe I've made a mistake.